# Showing $x^2\sin \frac {1}{x}$ is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Show that the function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2\sin \frac {1}{x}$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is surjective.

What I thought that if I could show that for every $n\in \mathbb N$ there is a $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=n$ and there is a $y \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(y)=-n$ then since $f$ is continuous by IVT $f$ is surjective. But I couldn't find such $x$ and $y$.

Comment: *Hint:* Can you determine the limit of $f(x)$ for $x \to \pm \infty$?

Comment: Function is odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2\sin \frac {1}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} x\frac{\sin \frac {1}{x}}{\frac1x} \to \infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} x^2\sin \frac {1}{x}=\lim_{x\to -\infty} x\frac{\sin \frac {1}{x}}{\frac1x} \to -\infty$$

and as $x \to 0$

$$\left|x^2\sin \frac {1}{x}\right| \to 0=f(0)$$

therefore the function is continuous and by IVT it is surjective.

Comment: Can you explain how the IVT is used?

Comment: @Mathfun Since $f$ is continuous (to be proven at $x=0$) by IVT we know that for any $y\in \mathbb R$ the equation $f(x)=y$ has at least one solution, therefore $f(x)$ is by definition surjective.

Comment: @Mathfun Note that continuity is a fundamental requirement and if you are not given that, you need to check it at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You have that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) =\lim_{x\to +\infty} x\cdot x\sin (\frac 1x) =+\infty$ and in the same way $\lim_{x\to - \infty} f(x) =-\infty $, so by IVT you have thesis.

Comment: The second limit should be $-\infty$.

Comment: You mean $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$

Comment: Yes sure, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't we also check that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$?

Comment: @user: From OPs statement *“since $f$ is continuous”* I would assume that they already know that.

Comment: @MartinR It is not stated in the problem setting. I think that it is also a crucial point.

Comment: $f$ is continuous in 0 since $|f(x)|=x^2|\sin (\frac 1x )|\le x^2\to 0$ for $x\to 0$. @user

Comment: @AlessandroCigna Yes of course! My comment was for the asker in order they are aware about the condition.

Comment: @AlessandroCigna If it was a given or trivial for the asker is fine, otherwise it is needed to discuss also that aspect in my opinion.